# How can I create a NavigationController in a view-based application?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How should I go about creating a NavigationController for use in a view-based application?

Comment: Start a Navigation Based App and migrate your code.

Comment: You need to be more specific. We can't help you unless you make it clear exactly what your problem is and perhaps show some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code

In delegate .h class

```
      MyViewController *viewController;
```

In delegate  .m class

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

UINavigationController *nvcontrol =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[window addSubview:nvcontrol.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Here "MyViewController" should be replaced by your viewcontroller.

All The Best.

Answer (score 1):

- [UINavigationController tutorial w/ multiple xibs and data sharing](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7224-uinavigationcontroller-tutorial-w-multiple-xibs-data-sharing.html)
- [View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

in delegate.h

```
@class test24ViewController;

@interface test24AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    test24ViewController *viewController;
    UINavigationController *nav;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet test24ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *nav;
```

in delegate.m

```
@synthesize nav;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [nav pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```